# Javascript slideonlyone to slide div and link to page

Tags: javascript, slider

I am using the script below on my wordpress sidebar menu and it works perfectly.  However on some of the menu options I want to slide the div AND link to a page.  I've worked on this all morning with no success.  Can you please tell me what I need to add to this script to make it work?  Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) { 
    $('div[name|="events"]').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) { 
            $(this).slideDown(500);
        } else { 
            $(this).slideUp(500);
        }
    }
);
}
```

The page I am referencing is: http://www.nicksardone.com/slide-down.php

The javascript in the question is a function that when a top level menu item is selected it slides the selected div down to show other links. The question is I want the top level menu option (Human resources) for example to slide the div down AND link to another page on the site. Hope that clarifies...

Comment: please wrap your code in the code tags.   Also include a link to a working example so we can look at the website in context? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the question is not clear, what do you mean with "and link to page" ?

EDIT:

if your problem is that clicking on the div it works fine but clicking on the link doesn't work.
you have to call the slideonlyone function on the **href** property of the link **passing as parameter the id of his parent div**.
link this:

```
<a id="someID" href="javascript:slideonlyOne(MyParentDivID)">text</a>
```

but if you want that it opens another page:

```
    function slideonlyone(thechosenone, url) { 
        $('div[name|="events"]').each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) { 
                $(this).slideDown(500);window.open(url);

            } else { 
                $(this).slideUp(500);
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Comment: Here is a sample page  http://nicksardone.com/slide-down.php

When you click the menu item I want the div to slide dowN, which works perfectly\, and link to another page.

Comment: I am sorry.   The page I am referencing is: nicksardone.com/slide-down.php   The javascript in the question is a function that when a top level menu item is selected it slides the selected div down to show other links.  The question is I want the top level menu option (Human resources) for example to slide the div down AND link to another page on the site.  Hope that clarifies...

Comment: Safouene BHA, Thank you, that worked except that each top level menu item would need to link to a different page.

Comment: you can add an attribute on the div example <div id="MyID" url="http://....">...</div> and change the function like this
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) { 
        $('div[name|="events"]').each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) { 
                $(this).slideDown(500);window.open($(this).attr("url"));

            } else { 
                $(this).slideUp(500);
            }
        }
    );

}